# Android wait 1 minute without stopping thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How do I wait one minute in my Android application without stopping the thread? I need to play a sound every minute for X rounds. I have all the code working except the waiting code.

```
public void startRounds(View v)
{
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ding);
    mp.start();

    EditText txtRounds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRounds);
    rounds = Integer.parseInt(txtRounds.getText().toString());

    oneSession();
}

private void oneSession()
{
    //this needs to be replaced with my new wait one minute function
    SystemClock.sleep(60000);

    MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ding);
    mp2.start();

    if (rounds != 1) {
        rounds--;
        oneSession();
    }
}
```

---

Solved:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                  //do something
            }
        }, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: So you want to stop the thread without stopping it? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: waiting is waiting how do you wait without stop or pause thread?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you really want but it here `do something` will run after `60 * 1 seconds`

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                      //do something
                }
            }, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked really well! I edited the post so other people can see it, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler which will get executed without blocking thread.eg

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /**put your code inside this
                 * this method will get exceuted after 1 min without stopping thread
                 * same thing can be recursive based on your requirement*/

            }
        },60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the minute in another thread because on the UI Thread de sound will stop:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(60000)
                    }catch(InterruptedExcpetion e){

                    }
            }).start();
```